# discord.js image search with pages

Tags: discord.js

is there a way to add pages for this command.
e.g | https://gyazo.com/e6782fc9386f9d15c7cc52dabeb8844e (it can be with reactions or buttons)

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "img",
    description: "Search for an image!",
    category: "utility",
    cooldown: {type: "map", time: 10},
    aliases: ["is", "imgsearch"],
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        if (!args) client.err(message);
        gis(args.join(" "), logResults);
        async function logResults(error, results){
            if (error)return client.err(message);

            let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * results.length);
            let image = results[random].url

            const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setImage(image)
            .setColor("#2f3136");
            return message.reply(embed);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by pages? Since you select the image at random, there is no way to add pages.

Comment: for example, i want my bot to react with these two reactions '⬅️, ➡️' and ppl can go back & forward instead of using the command over and over again

Comment: just like the bot notsobot when u use the command .img u can basically go back and forward with images

Comment: You can try **[Pagination](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js-pagination)**

Comment: But what does "backward and forward" mean when you select the image at random...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to add two reactions '⬅️, ➡️', and await till user reacts with one of them. (working with reactions is nicely described [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html))
Your code would look like this:

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "img",
    description: "Search for an image!",
    category: "utility",
    cooldown: {type: "map", time: 10},
    aliases: ["is", "imgsearch"],
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        if (!args) client.err(message);
        gis(args.join(" "), logResults);
        async function logResults(error, results){
            if (error)return client.err(message);

            let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * results.length);
            let image = results[random].url

            const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setImage(image)
            .setColor("#2f3136");
            // Awaiting till the message gets sent so we can add reactions & await users to react
            const msg = await message.reply(embed);
            // Adding reactions
            await msg.react('⬅️');
            await msg.react('➡️');

            // Create a filter so only when original author reacts with ⬅️ or ➡️ the message is edited.
            const filter = (reaction, user) => {
                return ['⬅️', '➡️'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
            };

            // Await until user reacts
            message.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] })
    .then(collected => {
        const reaction = collected.first();

        if (reaction.emoji.name === '⬅️') {
            await msg.reactions.removeAll();
            let image = results[random-1].url

            const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setImage(image)
            .setColor("#2f3136");
            msg.edit(embed);
        } else {
            await msg.reactions.removeAll();
            let image = results[random+1].url

            const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setImage(image)
            .setColor("#2f3136");
            msg.edit(embed);
        }
    })
    .catch(collected => {
        message.reply('Your time to open next or previous image expired!');
    });
        }
    }
}
```